# What are these weird clippings on edit mode when my object has subdivision surface on?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, 3d-view

The object looks fine to me in object mode but on edit mode i see this clippings through the object's box selection. It is supposed to look like that or is there an issue that i'm not noticing?[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Nothing seems wrong here, it's just some z-fighting between your edit mesh and the subsurf mesh.

Z-fighting is when two faces (in this case, the edit mesh face and the subsurf faces) occupy the same space, so they "fight" over which one gets rendered first.